# query to get userimage path and user information from two different tables

Tags: java, sql, database, struts2

I am developing a photo album web application in which I am using two tables `USER_INFORMATION` and `USER_PHOTO`. `USER_INFORMATION` contains only user record which is one record, `USER_PHOTO` contains more than one photo form a single user. I want to get the number of user information along with their userimage path and store it in to a Java Pojo variable like a list so that I can display it using display tag in struts 2.

The table goes like this.

```
        USER_PHOTO                                   USER_INFORMATION
   =======================                     =================================
   | IMAGEPATH | USER_ID |                     | USER_NAME | AGE | ADDRESS |ID |
   =======================                     =================================
   |xyz        | 1       |                     | abs       | 34  |  sdas   | 1 | 
   |sdas       | 1       |                     | asddd     | 22  | asda    | 2 |
   |qwewq      | 2       |                     | sadl      | 121 | asd     | 3 |
   | asaa      | 1       |                     ==================================
   | 121       | 3       | 
   =======================
```

As you can see user_id=1 has 3 photos and user_id=2 has 2 photos and 3 has one photo. Now I want to write the query to get user information along with their imagepath.

So I tried using the code below to store it in an ArrayList, my code in Action class:

```
 public ArrayList loadData() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
ArrayList userList = new ArrayList();
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
PreparedStatement ps = null;
try {
    String name;
    String fatherName;
    int Id;
    String filePath;
    int age;
    String address;
    String query = "SELECT NAME,FATHERNAME,AGE,ADDRESS,ID,FILEPATH FROM USER_INFORMATION ,USER_PHOTO WHERE ID=USER_ID";
    ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        name = rs.getString(1);
        fatherName = rs.getString(2);
        age = rs.getInt(3);
        address = rs.getString(4);
        Id = rs.getInt(5);
        UserData list = new UserData();
        list.setName(name);
        list.setFatherName(fatherName);
        list.setAge(age);
        list.setAddress(address);
        userList.add(list);
    }
    ps.close();
    con.close();
```

And my JSP goes like this:

```
<display:table id="data" name="sessionScope.UserForm.userList" requestURI="/userAction.do" pagesize="1" >
  <display:column property="name" title="NAME" sortable="true"   />
  <display:column property="fatherName" title="User Name" sortable="true"  />
  <display:column property="age" title="AGE" sortable="true"   />
  <display:column property="address" title="ADDRESS" sortable="true"  />
  <display:column property="filePath" title="PATH" sortable="true"  />
</display:table>
```

So while I am displaying it shows every userinformation correctly but in the path column is blank.

Expected output: I want to dispaly user information name, age, address, and IMAGEPATH (which is more than one record in another table).

Comment: What database are you using?  When a user has more than one imagepath, do you want to use all images paths, the first one, the last one?

Comment: Java db and i want to get all the images path

Comment: And how would you display them? All the paths as comma separated values in the "filePath" column of your table?

Comment: i have read some thing on GROUP_CONCAT() function i am planning to use that to concatenate to the string variable and set it. @beny23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small tip : Use column names rather then their indices when reading data from the result set.
Example : `fatherName = rs.getString("FATHERNAME");`

This will be more easy to maintain incase you change your query and is much clearer.

Now, where in your code do you read the FILEPATH column ?! You only read the first five columns (name, father_name, age, address, id) but nothing is read for the FILEPATH column.

Comment: Actually i removed That line its like this..                              **filePath=rs.getString(6);** when  i display it the name age fathername adress will repeat for all the filePath. in detail if a user have 6 filePath six records will be displayed with same information except filepath value will be differed